# RDS User CAL Licences - over provisioned and still giving out CALs

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds, cals

My understanding is that RDS CALs are not concurrent so both RDS implementation seem to be issuing more then they should be, users are not being effected in either case.

Is this expected behavior?

I'm in the middle of working out an upgrade path to 2016 so i would like to avoid any catastrophic unscheduled outages.

I work across 2 different businesses, they are not connected in any way.

- Domain A - 2008r2

  - RDS Licensing server on Domain Controller
  - [RDS Licencing Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGOHB.png)
  - 30 User CALs, currently issued 62
  - No interruption to users trying to login
- Domain B - 2012r2 - RDS Licencing server on single Terminal Server

  - RDS Licencing server on Terminal Server
  - [RDS Licensing Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPkiL.png)
  - 30 User CALS, currently issued 67
  - 20 User CALs, available 20, issued 0
    -No interruption to user logins